# Dynamically generate list of arguments for ffmpeg in C

Tags: c, memory-management, ffmpeg, malloc

I'm currently writing a video conversion daemon in C. It calls ffmpeg using execvp.

I've created a struct called "ffmpeg_job" that represents a conversion job to be completed. I'd like to dynamically allocate the arguments to ffmpeg for each job, so that I can free one of these structs and its list of arguments after the job is completed.

I started writing the function that dynamically allocates the list of arguments, but I feel like the way I'm going about it is quite naive. The code is below.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I'm thinking now that I will have a static string list of arguments for each level of quality, then sprintf into it and strtok it into a char **

```
char ** generate_arguments(
    char *filepath,
    ph5v_format format,
    ph5v_quality quality)
{
    char ** arguments;
    if (format == ph5v_MP4) {
        mp4_arguments = {
            "-i", "%%INPUT FILEPATH 1",
            "-vcodec", "libx264",
            "-preset", "%%X264 PRESET 5",
            "-b:v", "%%VIDEO BITRATE 7",
            "-strict", "-2",
            "-acodec", "aac",
            "-b:a", "%%AUDIO BITRATE 13",
            "-ar", "%%AUDIO SAMPLERATE 15",
            "-ac", "2",
            "-y", "%%OUTPUT FILEPATH 19"
        }

        arguments = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 20);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                char *argument = malloc(strlen(filepath) + 1);
                strcpy(argument, filepath);
                arguments[1] = argument;
            } else if (i == 5) {
                if (quality == ph5v_LOW || quality == ph5v_MEDIUM) {
                    char *argument = malloc(strlen("fast") + 1);
                    strcpy(argument, "fast");
                    arguments[5] = argument;
                } else if (quality == ph5v_HIGH || quality == ph5v_ULTRA ) {
                    char *argument = malloc(strlen("medium") + 1);
                    strcpy(argument, "medium");
                    arguments[5] = argument;
                }
            } else if (i == 7) {
                if (quality ==
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed code seems to be functionally fine. Some observations about the current code

I assume that you are populating all the odd number indices inside the `for` loop. Hence, the loop could be potentially optimized as `for(i = 1; i < 20; i++)`.

In case of quality, I presume you have a pre-fixed set of options like **fast** , **medium** etc. In the current implementation, you are calculating the string length for allocation of memory. This could potentially be replaced with an array lookup, where the array element corresponds to a structure having the name and size already stored. For example, the code could be as below

```
if (quality == ph5v_LOW || quality == ph5v_MEDIUM) 
    index = 0;

argument = malloc(sizeof(quality_array[index].size + 1));
strcpy(argument, quality_array[index].strname);
```

where `quality_array` is an array of structures as defined below

```
 typedef struct qual_param {
      int size;
      char *strnamne;
 }
```

Comment: I ended up going with my idea of printf-ing into some huge string allocated for each permutation of format and quality, and then tokenizing them. I should accept your answer for taking a serious look, though.